# Windows Media Player control - get/set video position?

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using Windows Media Player ActiveX (axWindowsMediaPlayer) component in C# WinForms application. Is it possible to get and set the current position of the video that is being played using this control?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = positionInSeconds;`