# set a starting point end point of media players by using c#/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, media-player, playback, axwindowsmediaplayer

currently I am trying to make a surveillance system program program where I can set my starting point of playing a video end end it at some point according to the time i write on the text box. for example I want to see the footage from 12:20 to 12:30   Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Media Player control - get/set video position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590291/windows-media-player-control-get-set-video-position)

Comment: Please consider doing a bit of research (looks like it is duplicated) and try somethi ng. In case you get into problems provide a [mcve]. As it is written it is either duplicated or too broad.